# How to create mysql connection with pool request?

Tags: mysql, node.js

how include Setup Connections and Parser?

```
var mysql   = require('mysql');
var pool = mysql.createPool({
   host     : 'localhost',
   user     : 'medb',
   password : '123458',
   database : 'test',
   connectionLimit: 100
});
```

What would be next ?

Comment: Hi this is complete step to get mysql connection with pool request.

Comment: thanks thats work for me now.

Answer (score 1):

Hi this is complete step to get mysql connection with pool request.

```
var mysql   = require('mysql');

//Setup Connections and Parser
var pool = mysql.createPool({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'me',
    password : '12345',
    database : 'A2014',
    connectionLimit: 100
});

pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {

    connection.query( 'select count(9) from mytbl;', function(err, rows) {
    connection.release();
    });
    pool.end();
});
```